# How do I check for an empty slice?

Tags: go, slice

I am calling a function that returns an empty array if there are no values.

When I do this it doesn't work:

```
if r == [] {
    fmt.Println("No return value")            
}
```

The work around I'm using is:

```
var a [0]int
if r == a {
    fmt.Println("No return value")            
}
```

But declaring a variable just to check the return value doesn't seem right. What's the better way to do this?

Comment: Go is not javascript! Read the basics: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: More things - first - array is not a slice. Array is type, that has fixed number of elements, therefore question makes sense only for slice. Second - it won't work, if you initialize those slices. Third - and what about if len(a) == 0?

Comment: Does your workaround compile? I can't see how it would unless `r` is also of type `[0]int` but in that case the two (empty) arrays would always compare equal.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes it does work. The return type of the function is int[]

Answer (score 172, accepted):

[`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) returns the number of elements in a slice or array.

Assuming `whatever()` is the function you invoke, you can do something like:

```
r := whatever()
if len(r) > 0 {
  // do what you want
}
```

or if you don't need the items

```
if len(whatever()) > 0 {
  // do what you want
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that a slice which is just declared, like, `var num []int`, also returns the len to be zero. i.e, `len(num) == 0`

Comment: @nawaz yes but that’s expected is it not? Even in case var num []int = nil then len(num) returns 0. This is just perfect imo. This way I don’t need to do a nil check beforehand. If I do need to check for nil I can just add that explicitly. But again to the point of uninitaliazed var, agree it should be 0. since len can only return an int then this makes perfect sense. A len return val of -1 would be very confusing to see imo.

Comment: Do you know whether `len` traverses the whole slice in order to compute the length (and therefore its time complexity would be equal to the length of the slice)? Or is it constant time?

Comment: @AlexM. `len` operates in constant time. The length of the slice is stored as part of the slice, next to capacity and the pointer to the data.

Comment: @rv.kvetch how is `nil` having a valid length perfect? Anything other than a nil pointer exception in this case seems needlessly obscure.

Answer (score 25):

You can just use the `len` function.

```
if len(r) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("No return value")            
}
```

Although since you are using arrays, an array of type `[0]int` (an array of int with size 0) is different than `[n]int` (n array of int with size n) and are not compatible with each other.

If you have a function that returns arrays with different lengths, consider using slices, because function can only be declared with an array return type having a specific length (e.g. `func f() [n]int`, `n` is a constant) and that array will have n values in it (they'll be zeroed) even if the function never writes anything to that array.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the inbuilt function provided by Golang

> len()

It will helps you to easily find a slice is empty or not.

```
if len( yourFunction() ) == 0 {
    // It implies that your array is empty.
}
```